# runtime of a block code

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory

Can someone please explain to me why this code has a runtime complexity T(n) of 2lgn+2. I thought it should be lgn+2.

```
public static reduce(int n){
 int result = 0;
 while (n >1){
   n = n/2;
   result = result +1;
 }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: Well, it depends on what complexity you assign to each line of code...

Answer (score 1):

Presumably each line is assumed to take 1 unit of time (not including the `n > 1` check).

So `int result = 0;`, `n = n/2;`, `result = result +1;` and `return result;` each classify as taking 1 unit of time.

2 comes from `int result = 0;` and `return result;` each being executed once.

2 log<sub>2</sub>n comes from `n = n/2;` and `result = result +1;` each being executed log<sub>2</sub>n times.

**Note:**

`n > 1` could also classify as a unit of time resulting in 3 log<sub>2</sub>n + 2.

`n = n/2;` and `result = result +1;` could each classify as taking 2 units of time resulting in (with the above) 5 log<sub>2</sub>n + 2.

It's all very subjective.

The only across the board agreement would be c log<sub>2</sub>n + d for some c and d.

Comment: @WaadKahouli Remember to [upvote and/or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) this answer if you found it helpful.